# Is redux is same 100 percent in both react js and in react native or any little bit change

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

question is that is redux is same 100 percent same for both react JS and in react native and if there is any little bit change then at what place it will be different.

for example i have a redux code for react JS and i want to implement same as it is in react native can i copy paste that structure and code, or there will be any little change????

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see if you have any problems? IF you do, then post here and look for a solution?

Comment: It's the same. Yet, I would  suggest to try it out